# How to split an ellipse in TikZ and chose the section I want to write in?

Tags: tikz-pgf, ellipse

I tried to split an ellipse in 2 parts (like on the picture) as it's possible easily with rectangle, but it looks like it's not working the same, so how can I do that? (Below the code  I tried)

```
splitEllipse/.style={
    ellipse split,
    draw, 
    shape aspect=2, 
    inner sep=2pt,
    text centered,
    fill=blue!10!white,
    font=\itshape
}
```

```
splitEllipse/.style={
    ellipse split part=2,
    draw, 
    shape aspect=2, 
    inner sep=2pt,
    text centered,
    fill=blue!10!white,
    font=\itshape
}
```

None of these codes is working.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you check [the manual](https://tikz.dev/library-shapes#pgf.ellipse:split)? Please provide a compilable code example that shows what exactly does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your options don't work for the shape `ellipse split`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
    splitEllipse/.style={draw, fill=blue!10!white, shape=ellipse split, align=center, minimum width=6cm, inner sep=2pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[splitEllipse]{upper text\nodepart{lower}lower text\\second line};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A huge thank, you're a timesavior !!

Comment: @avirsty: It may seem strange, but on this site we typically don't use comments for giving thanks. Instead, we show appreciation by [upvoting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) all helpful answers. Also, when you post a question, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands and ends with `\end{document}`, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: Copy ! Just one more question when there's a lot of attributes in the lower part, the ellipse takes the form of an egg, is there a way to prevent this?